# import csv into sugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I am trying to import a csv file into sugarCRM but on step 2 my data looks like: ;cqà,ý¼nÉBÏÛï÷£ýd$ÕÆóWHkÂQËrÅTyÀÁ

I have just no idea whatsoever what to do. I've tried researching how to import and I am just not seeing anything that helps me with my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting your input file format to UTF-8 and see if that solves the problem. Sounds like a problem with file encoding...